# Trouble writing Python code to remove bytes from a defined file index position

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a simple python3 file which will list the desired (visible) files in a directory in a file, then edit each file so that bytes at index positions 5 to 15 are deleted and the modified file saved to an output folder.

I use the following file to gather the filenames into an output file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os
import sys

path = '.'
print('Filenames and filename length below.')
my_file = open("output_filenames.txt", "w")
my_file.close()
for file in os.listdir(path):
    current_file = os.path.join(path, file)
    print(current_file)
    print(len(current_file) - 2)
    print("""running getFilenames2.py , listing files from the directory once, 
    with clean_string2.py and new_editor.py""")
    x = current_file.strip("./")
    my_file = open("output_filenames.txt", "a")
    my_file.writelines(x)
    my_file.writelines('\n')
    my_file.close()
    # this file prints the filenames in the current directory. 
print("This is the end of getFilenames2.py")
```

Next I want to strip the extra "./" part of the generated filenames in the list and also remove hidden file filenames and the three python files needed to do all of this.
In the next file, I copy the list to a new file, then I modify this file to remove the unwanted filenames. There are a lot of them because i also tried to get this to work by deploying to Pythonanywhere.com , and these are the folder names and hidden files or files that I don't want to list, copy or modify in their setup.
About halfway down the list of files to remove, I have commented out a section of code which illustrates a new way that I am working on to remove the unwanted files. Lines 92 to 108. Should I switch to this code format?
Also I am worried about deleting data as I go, that's why I write to a completely new file to start and every time I modify a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os
import sys
os.system('python getFilenames2.py')
my_file = open("output_filenames.txt", "r")
file_content = my_file.read()
my_file.close()
x = file_content
my_file = open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "a")
my_file.write(x)
my_file.close()
# print(x)
print(type(x))
# remove certain filenames from the list: DS_Store, clean_string.py, output_filenames.txt ,getFilenames.py , 
# output_cleaned_filenames.txt ,output_pruned_filenames.txt, getFilenames.py
# for online use of pythonanywhere website configuration, remove the following filenames:
# virtualenvs, vimrc, local, gitconfig, pythonstartup.py, bashrc, ipython, profile ,output_folder
my_file = open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "w")
my_file.write(x)
my_file.close()
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("DS_Store"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop DS_Store from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("virtualenvs"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop virtualenvs from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("vimrc"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop vimrc from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("local"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop local from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("gitconfig"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close() 
# the last seven lines stop gitconfig from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("pythonstartup.py"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close() 
# the last seven lines stop pythonstartup.py from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("bashrc"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close() 
# the last seven lines stop bashrc from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("ipython"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop ipython from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("profile"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop profile from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
# with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
#    lines = f.readlines() 
#with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
#    pruned_new_f = new_f.strip("output_folder")
#    pruned_new_f.write(new_f)
#   
# infile = "output_pruned_filenames.txt"
# outfile = "cleaned_file.txt"

# delete_list = ["word_1", "word_2", "word_n"]
# with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as fout:
#     for line in fin:
#        for word in delete_list:
#           line = line.replace(word, "")
#        fout.write(line)
# my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop output_folder from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt         
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("clean_string.py"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop clean_string.py from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("output_filenames.txt"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop output_filenames from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("getFilenames.py"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop getFilenames.py from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("output_cleaned_filenames.txt"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop output_cleaned_filenames.txt from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
with open("output_cleaned_filenames.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "w") as new_f:
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith("output_pruned_filenames.txt"):
            new_f.write(line)
my_file.close()
# the last seven lines stop output_pruned_filenames.txt from being listed in output_pruned_filenames.txt
my_file = open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "r")
file_content = my_file.read()
my_file.close()
print(file_content)
print("This is the end of clean_string.py")
print('output_pruned_filenames.txt is the final output file')
print('These are the files in the current directory.')
```

This last file is the most trouble, it is the file which will delete some bytes from each listed file when copied to the output folder. The bytes are deleted from index 5 to index 14.
I copy the first 5 bytes to the first input file, then I copy the bytes from index 15 to the end of the input file and save them as the second output file.
After this I concatenate the output files together and place in the third output file. There is a problem at line 27. Should I be referring still to "working_file" ?

```
# edit_listPytest9.py
import os
os.system('python clean_string2.py')
count = 0
if not os.path.exists('output_folder'):
    os.makedirs('output_folder')
with open("output_pruned_filenames.txt", "rt") as myfile:
    for myline in myfile:
        x = myline.rstrip("\n")
        print("\n")
        print("This is the filename.")
        count += 1
        with open(x, "rt") as working_file:
                file_content = working_file.read()
                # print("Here is the content of")
                # print(file_content)
                new_filename = x.rstrip(".txt")
                print(new_filename)
                print(count)
                id = str(count)
                print(new_filename + "_" + id + ".txt")
                # f = file("path/to/file", "w")
                dynamic_filename = new_filename + "_" + id + ".txt"
                print(dynamic_filename)
                with open('output_folder/' + dynamic_filename, 'w') as my_file:
                    my_file.writelines(file_content)
                    my_file = open( working_file, "r")
                    file_content = my_file.read()
                    my_file.close()
                    # print(file_content)
                    print("\n" + 'This is the length of the input file, ' + dynamic_filename + ', it includes spaces and line returns.')
                    print(len(file_content))
                    # print((file_content[0]) + (file_content[1]) + (file_content[2]) + (file_content[3]) + (file_content[4]) + (file_content[5]) + (file_content[6]) + (file_content[7]) + (file_content[8]) + (file_content[9]) + (file_content[10]) + (file_content[11]) + (file_content[12]) + (file_content[13]) + (file_content[14]) + (file_content[15]) + (file_content[16]) + (file_content[17]) + (file_content[18]) + (file_content[19]) + (file_content[20]) + (file_content[21]) + (file_content[22]) + (file_content[23]) + (file_content[24]) + (file_content[25]) + (file_content[26]) + (file_content[27]) + (file_content[28]) + (file_content[29]) + (file_content[30]) + (file_content[31]) + (file_content[32]) + (file_content[33]) + (file_content[34]) + (file_content[35]) + (file_content[36]) + (file_content[37]) + (file_content[38]) + (file_content[39]) + (file_content[40]))
                    # print('This is the first 41 characters of 'dynamic_filename '  above.' + '\n')
                    # print('\n' + 'This is the first 10 characters of  'dynamic_filename ' below.' + '\n')
                    file_start = ((file_content[0]) + (file_content[1]) + (file_content[2]) + (file_content[3]) + (file_content[4]) + (file_content[5]) + (file_content[6]) + (file_content[7]) + (file_content[8]) + (file_content[9]))
                    # chunk_removed = some number of bytes removed
                    # write back to new file to edit out Chunk
                    # first, strip the .txt extension from dynamic_filename
                    dynamic_filename = dynamic_filename.rstrip(".txt")
                    # this filename will have to be made out of dynamic_filename and indicate purpose: is output_file1.txt originally output_file1 =
                    # dynamic_filename + output_file1.txt
                    my_file = open('output_folder/' + dynamic_filename + "output_file1.txt", "w")
                    # write to output file number 1
                    my_file.writelines(file_start)
                    my_file.close()
                    # output to console or terminal
                    # print(file_start)
                    # print("\n" + 'This is the length of 'dynamic_filename'output_file1.txt, the first output file.')
                    # print(len(file_start))
                    # file_remaining = my_file.read() # use seek to start read from index [10 + chunk_removed]# e.. chunk_removed = 5 characters 10 + 5 = 15
                    my_file = open(working_file, "r")
                    my_file.seek(15)
                    file_remaining = my_file.read()
                    my_file.close()
                    my_file = open('output_folder/' + dynamic_filename + "output_file2.txt", "w")
                    my_file.writelines(file_remaining)
                    my_file.close()
                    # output_file2.txt starts with the 16th character. Remember that this is the number of characters since index starts at 0.
                    # After 15 characters.
                    # Creating a list of filenames three files - header.txt, output_file1.txt, output_file2.txt
                    filenames = ['header.txt', 'output_folder/' + dynamic_filename + 'output_file1.txt', 'output_folder/' + dynamic_filename + 'output_file2.txt']
                    # Open output_file3 in write mode to create it and write
                    with open('output_folder/' + dynamic_filename + 'output_file3.txt', 'w') as outfile:
                       # Iterate through list
                        for names in filenames:
                           # Open each file in read mode
                            with open(names) as infile:
                                # read the data from  header, file1 and
                                # file2 and write it in file3
                                outfile.write(infile.read())
                                # Add '\n' to enter data of file2 (disabled by comment at the start of this line)
                                # from next line
                                # outfile.write("\n")
                                # print(outfile)
                                my_file.close()
```

Comment: Why are you doing `os.path.join(path, file)` and then stripping off the `./` that this adds? If you don't want the directory prefix, don't add it in the first place.

Comment: `writelines()` is normally used with a list or other iterable containing strings. If you're writing a single string, just use `write()`.

Comment: I plead ignorance, I just learned Python a few weeks ago and i have been just adding snippets of code together until something works. That makes sense that it should just be os.path(file) to list the files in a directory.

Comment: This code below works to generate a list of filenames in a directory.import os
import sys

path = '.'
print('Filenames and filename length below.')
my_file = open("output_filenames.txt", "w")
my_file.close()
for file in os.listdir(path):
    current_file = os.path.join("",file)
    # os.path.join(path, file) is the original code snippet

Answer (score 1):

`strip()` and `rstrip()` are not for removing substrings. They remove all characters in the list at the beginning or end, not just the exact string. You can use `re.sub()` to remove substrings at the beginning or end, e.g.

```
import re

new_filename = re.sub(r'\.txt$', '', filename)
```

You're making writing the desired bytes much harder than it needs to be. You don't need extra files, just slice the string that you read.

```
with open(x, "r") as working_file:
    file_contents = working_file.read()
# code to calculate dynamic_filename
with open(os.path.join("output_folder", dynamic_filename), "w") as my_file:
    my_file.write(file_contents[0:5] + file_contents[15:])
```

Comment: Thank-you so much for your answer, I'm sure that it will lead me to writing a working Python script for my purpose. I think that you meant to say that I should concatenate file_contents[0:4] and file_contents[15:] , since I am "deleteing" ten bytes starting after the fifth byte. sorry if that wasn't clear. Am I right or is there an other detail I missed? I missed the edge case??

Comment: Slice are non-inclusive of the second index, so `0:5` means bytes 0 through 4.

Comment: Can you write this same thing with Pathlib instead of os.path.join ?

Comment: I'm sure you could.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I appreciate your help for this newbie.